# Accellera SystemC error with a large number of SC_THREAD

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, stack, systemc

In the context of a SystemC simulation with many `SC_THREAD` processes (> 32000), I am facing the following error with the Accellera 2.3.1 implementation on an Intel X86 platform running Ubuntu 15.04:

```
sc_cor_qt.cpp:114: virtual void sc_core::sc_cor_qt::stack_protect(bool) 
Assertion `ret == 0' failed
```

The default implementation of the SystemC kernel uses user-level threads (also called coroutines) to implement the SystemC processes. The static processes (`SC_THREAD` and `SC_CTHREAD`) are initialized in the `sc_simcontext.cpp` line 759 `thread_p->prepare_for_simulation()` This function will create the user-level thread object and then enable stack protection.

The stack of the user-level thread is allocated in the heap of the SystemC simulation process by the following line `cor->m_stack = new char[cor->m_stack_size]`

The issue I am facing happens in the stack protection function after the creation, that uses an `mprotect` system call to make the page just after the stack of the user-level thread (again, being in the heap of the **Linux** process) non accessible at all (`PROT_NONE`). The error (`ENOMEM`) I have from `mprotect` says that this page we want to protect has never been mapped into the process **or** that the kernel was not able allocate some internal structures while running the `mprotect` call. Unfortunately I am not able to know which of these two errors happens and how to fix it.

Moreover, I can't see where this extra page is allocated in the heap of the Linux process before the `mprotect` call is made.

Does anyone know what is going and/or what can I do know to further debug this issue ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743555/munmap-failure-with-enomem-with-private-anonymous-mapping) question explains your issue on Linux I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the maximum number of memory mappings allowed by a single process. Each `mprotect` call leads to a single memory mapping, resulting in a total number of mappings greater than the default limit of my system. To increase this limit, one has to use:

```
sudo sysctl vm/max_map_count=524240
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the majority of your storage should be on the heap, but try increasing stack size in case that is limiting allocation of some SC objects.

Check current stacksize:    (from csh)

limit      (or from sh: ulimit -a)

If not already unlimited, increase with one of these:

limit stacksize 1024m      (from sh: ulimit -s 1024000)

limit stacksize unlimited  (from sh: ulimit -s unlimited)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem was about the number of memory mappings. See my answer